# How did Stark's autonomous suits come back in Iron Man 3?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-3

In *Iron Man 3*, all of Stark's autonomous suits were destroyed in the helicopter attack, how then did they reappear again in the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They were not all destroyed in the helicopter attack. The only suits we saw destroyed at that time were the Marks One through Seven, which had a prominent display above the vault containing the other suits. The vault remained apparently undamaged, so the remaining suits (which we can assume consisted of the Marks Eight through Forty-One) were able to join Stark and Rhodes in Miami once the debris covering the vault was cleared.

Answer (score 6):

If memory serves the suits were in some kind of vault underneath his house.  The house fell into the sea but, the vault was still there.

Comment: So basically not any robot destroy they all r safe?

Comment: Assuming I'm parsing your sentence correctly, yes, they were kept safe in the vault, albeit underwater.

Comment: it's been awhile since I've seen the movie but I just assumed it was under the house separate from the main foundation (and normally reached by elevator) and so survived the attack and remained covered by debris.  None of the movie shots showed it (the armor vault) or simulated it being underwater.

Comment: There were several very brief comments by Jarvis to Tony about construction crews and their progress during the movie. They were easy to miss, but they explained that once enough of the wreckage was cleared the suits were able to leave.